# Does a helping verb have to be followed by the main verb to form a complete sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, ellipses, parallelism

A friend wrote: "I just feel that now is a good time to reiterate that pluralization does not require an apostrophe."

In reply I wrote:

> Sometimes it does. "Mind your Ps and Qs" doesn't need them; however "Mind your p's and q's" does.

He replies: "Your p's and q's what?"

I'm 99.9% sure that I don't need to write "need them" at the end of my sentence in order for it to be a complete sentence, but I hate being wrong more than I like to correct people so I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine. First of all, the semicolon does not end the sentence so the first *need* is still there. As explained in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon#English) wikipedia page (which is quoting The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, Chapter 19, §7)

> While terminal marks (i.e., full stops, exclamation marks, and
> question marks) mark the end of a sentence, the comma, semicolon and
> colon are normally sentence internal, making them secondary boundary
> marks. The semicolon falls between terminal marks and the comma; its
> strength is equal to that of the colon.

In any case, you can have a perfectly grammatical (albeit [minor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_%28linguistics%29#Major_and_minor_sentences)) yet incomplete sentence:

> Is everything alright?
>
> Yes.

Comment: Alright, you've got me a little confused.  It sounds like you are saying that if I were to take just the part after the semicolon that it would be an incomplete sentence but that this is valid.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Also, in your example of an incomplete sentence ("Is everything alright?") there is a subject (everything) and a verb (is) so how is that incomplete?

Comment: (1) Ditch the idea that only 'complete sentences' are legal. (2) The 'incomplete sentence' terdon gives as an example here is the 'Yes.' Though I'd call it a 'sentence substitute'.

Comment: @BVernon what EdwinAshworth said. The example sentence was indeed _Yes_. Granted, it is an extreme example but it is actually perfectly grammatical despite not being a complete sentence. A sentence does not really _need_ to be complete in order to be grammatical. As for the semicolon, I am just saying that what you have posted is a single, long sentence. Therefore, you already have a valid verb in the first _need them_ and do not need another.

Comment: Thanks.  I understood the fact that an incomplete sentence is legal, but my friend said that I didn't 'complete' my sentence.  Being the overly analytical person that I am, I would prefer to be able to respond that it is in fact complete and not just legal. :)  Anyway, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 5):

He is making a little joke, and treating *p's* and *q's* as **possessives**.

He is saying that "Mind your p's and q's" is missing the noun that your p and q have. "Mind your p's and q's *descender,*" for example. [A *descender* is the part of the letter below the baseline it sits on.]

He is not commenting on the sentence overall, and you don't need "need them" after *does*.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the entire conversation but he did specifically say "You didn't finish your sentence."

Comment: I still reckon he meant your *reported* sentence in the quotes.